# Solarized colors for shell don't work in iTerm2 (and Terminal). All colors are the same

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, iterm, iterm2

How to make syntax highlighted for shell?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the '-G' option for ls. It enables colorized output.

Paul

Edited: added a dash before G

Comment: What do you mean by G option?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to type the dash '-'. Type 'ls -G' on the command line and you will see colorized output.

Comment: Alright, thank you. But how can automate such process?

Comment: put the following in your ~/.profile: alias ls="ls -G"

Comment: Do you know how to change xterm to xterm-256color in Terminal settings? I change to xterm-256color but it doesn't save it.

Comment: Sorry no. But you can add 'export TERM=xterm-256color' to your ~/.profile so that TERM is set every time you launch Terminal.

Comment: @KirillZhukov did I answer your question?